# Security Implications around a publicly viewable salted hash

Tags: database, security

I want to put a button on a third party website. The website will be open and public facing, which when clicked, would navigate to a page on my website.

The href in the button would include an id - a salted hash - that would be used to identify the source of the button click ie. the third party. So the button would have the form of  where the id is the salted hash.

I want to then use the salted hash to retrieve database credentials for the third party to be able to use in the webpages.

So , I have 2 questions around this given the security implications which I am unsure of but a bit nervous about.

1. Is this way of doing this secure and good practise or am I opening myself up to hacking?
2. Is there an alternate way of doing this without getting the third party to enter in the usual username/password type credentials?

Any help, comments - most appreciated!

Many thanks

Neville

Answer (score 0):

Your example seems to be quite a complex way of doing something simple. The security of this approach depends on the sensitivity of data you want to hold in the database and share with the user once they are redirected to your site. If this is public data, then it would be ok. Just do whatever is needed. If this is some kind of sensitive data - well, you want to authenticate the users at bare minimum.

Please note, having a salted hash/unsalted hash/secret/UUID/digest/whatever attached on some button somewhere on a page makes it publicly available and makes it impossible to be used as a security feature. There is little value in using a salted hash too. Go for some random value like an UUID version 4.

Why you want to extract credentials to the id and connect to the database is also a question. You usually want to have all the database connections open and lying in some connection pool to be able to fetch them quickly on demand. Opening a connection takes a long time so everything we can speed up by caching is of great value.

Comment: thanks very much for your answer, very helpful

Comment: Feel free to up-vote it if you like it. :D